# Calculating yearly active users in SQL

Tags: sql, database, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table `logins` with two columns: `user_id` and `login_date`. I would like to calculate the number of active users for each calendar year using the definition that for any given day, a `user_id` is said to be active on that date if it has had at least 1 login in the past 90 days. For example, if a `user_id` has a `login_date` of `2017-01-01`, then this `user_id` is said to be active for every day from `2017-01-01` to `2017-04-01`. The same `user_id` can have another `login_date` on `2017-02-01`, and subsequently will be active for every day from `2017-02-01` to `2017-05-01`. Using this definition, I would like to calculate the number of active users in 2017, 2018, 2019, and 2020.

Here's the input table, with a few examples:

```
+-----------+------------+
|  user_id  | login_date |
+-----------+------------+
|  0000000  | 2017-01-01 |
|  0000000  | 2017-02-01 |
|  0000001  | 2017-01-02 |
+-----------+------------+
```

The logic I have tried but do not think is correct:

For each login, make a column for each month the user will be active (3 months):

```
WITH all_missions AS (
SELECT
  user_id,
  format_datetime(login_date, 'yyyy-MM') AS first_active_date,
  format_datetime(date_add('month', 1, login_date), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS active_m1,
  format_datetime(date_add('month', 2, login_date), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS active_m2,
  format_datetime(date_add('month', 3, login_date), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS active_m3
FROM logins
),
```

Unpivot columns into rows:

```
active_months AS (
SELECT
  l.user_id,
  t2.active_month,
  t2.month_number
FROM logins l
CROSS JOIN unnest (
  array['active_m1', 'active_m2', 'active_m3'],
  array[active_m1, active_m2, active_m3]
) t2 (active_month, month_number)
),
```

Then count the distinct user count by only taking the year of each active month and aggregate:

```
SELECT
  substring(month_number, 1, 4) AS year_number,
  count(DISTINCT user_id) AS num_active_users
FROM active_months
GROUP BY 1
```

What is the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the number of yearly active users and not monthly active users, instead of determining `active_m1, active_m2, active_m3` (all active months) simply determine  `active_m3`. Having the `first_active_date` and `active_m3` is sufficient to determine whether the user was active within the current year or the next year.

You may try the following:

```sql
WITH all_missions AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        format_datetime(login_date, 'yyyy-MM') AS active_date
    FROM 
        logins
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        user_id,
        format_datetime(date_add('month', 3, login_date), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS active_date
     FROM logins
)
SELECT
  YEAR(active_date) AS year_number,
  count(DISTINCT user_id) AS num_active_users
FROM all_missions
GROUP BY 1
```

Let me know if this works for you.